# How do I print an odd number of symbols in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print an odd number of Hashtags(any symbols for that matter) in python.

The user inputs the number of rows.

For instance the user inputs: 3

Output:

"#"

"###"

"#####"

if the input is: 4

Output:

"#"

"###"

"#####"

"#######"

(without the quotations, that is.)

Comment: It does not make sense. Why does it print three lines for number 3 and only four for number 5?

Comment: You're right, mistake on my part! I've corrected the question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply create a loop and print the symbol equal to the loop iteration multiplied by two (and add 1) to get the sequence (1, 3, 5, ...)

```
rows = input()
for i in range(int(rows)):
    print('#' * (i*2 + 1))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a ton! I just have one question, how does the output move to the next line after each loop is completed?

Comment: Hi @PrateekKabra if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not responding to your question, the reason a newline appears is that the `print` statement by default appends a newline character `\n` at the end of each call to it. You can view the default arguments to the `print` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and you will see a default parameter called `end` that is by default set to the value `'\n'`.